# Invariant violation while implementing dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here I have made dropdown picker. I just want one reset button. When I click on reset button it should show the default value, not the selected and it should reset the chosen item.

I am experiencing an invariant violation with this code:

```
<Picker
    style={{width:'80%'}}
    selectedValue={this.state.PickerValue}
    onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex) => 
    this.setState({PickerValue:itemValue})}
    >
    <Picker.Item label="Select a option" value=""/>
    <Picker.Item label="About us" value="About us" />
    <Picker.Item label="Help" value="Help"/>
</Picker>


    </View>
     );
   }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
      welcome: {
      fontSize: 20,
      textAlign: 'center',
      margin: 10,
    },
      instructions: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: '#333333',
      marginBottom: 5,
    },
 });
```

Can someone help me find my syntax error?

Comment: i just one more help i want one reset button when i click it reset the list.

Comment: You removed the image.. 
If this is all the code, then you are closing a </View> without opening it. You should take a look into that